# iPhone App can autolaunch after device boot?

Tags: iphone, launch

Saw an app called [PhoneRecover](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/phonerecover/id377626768?mt=8) on the AppStore.

They advertise the following:

- PhoneRecover will automatically restart after a reboot on the iPhone 3GS and the iPhone 4 running iOS4.

How is this possible? What APIs are used to auto-launch an app after a boot?

Answer (score 3):

It's built into multi-tasking. "Backgrounded" apps are still in background after a reboot. Presumably the app does some work to re-instantiate itself and get its state going again the first time Core Location hits it in the background, but there's no other magic happening here. Any background-aware app will survive a reboot in a backgrounded state.

Comment: But what this description is saying is that it continues to run after a reboot. Are you saying that if I have a GPS app that is running in the background, and the phone reboots, the app will continue its operation automatically after the reboot without the explicit action?

Comment: Restart after reboot might only be done for approved VOIP apps.  Not sure about audio players.

Comment: The app in question does background Core Location services. Rebooting the phone doesn't unregister it from the background location services it's registered for. When it's pinged in the background, it gets a bit of time to run and handle the location update. So there it is running, in the background, after the phone is rebooted. Background CL services will actually LAUNCH an app that's registered for them, even if it's NOT backgrounded.

Comment: Has any tried this out, can they get a non-voip app to autoload after reboot?

Comment: I'm saying: I'VE tried this out. I actually bit myself with it accidentally and left an app I was building registered for location updates. Despite reboots and killing all apps manually, it kept coming back and my GPS kept running and eating my battery. I can completely vouch for the entire accuracy of my comments here through personal experimental results.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't count on this.  I was running MotionX GPS and let the battery run completely dead.  Upon restart MotionX was no longer running, broadcasting my position or tracking my position.  The broadcast option is persistent too (survives app restart).