# Is it possible to launch an application on system startup?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone App can autolaunch after device boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109305/iphone-app-can-autolaunch-after-device-boot)

Is it possible for an app to be brought to the front of the screen on system startup(i.e when the phone is switched on)? Similar to how android does the broadcast listener where you can bring the application to the front of the screen? Any examples if you can?

I am using models iPhone 3 and iPhone 4.

Comment: You need to add more details here?  What system? What devices etc?

Comment: I've tagged iPhone! So when the phone is switched on?

Comment: @Jack I don't think so. refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109305/iphone-app-can-autolaunch-after-device-boot

Comment: Thanks Marek. Tis a shame. Not sure why people are down voting this though, it's a decent question, it's not that hard to understand what I was asking. I even made a reference to Android to give an example.

Comment: @Jack Gleeman, I agree with you!

Comment: Downvoting means I lose reputation. I commonly use this site, and I don't down vote people unless completely needed. I don't see how this situation warrants a down vote for me. Thank you @EmptyStack for supporting!

Comment: +1[for being creative], I don't think so apple would allow this, It simply affects their style :). They want everything organised and nicely set-up, no bad user experience :). And I guess I like it like that.

Comment: Agreed. It's more or less what I've been asked to do, Captains orders -_- lol. If I am right though, all apps are loaded into the background on system (iPhone boot up) startup correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible, all you can do is use notification ,local or push to bring an application to the front when unlocked.

There is no way to set an app as startup app when turning the system on.